# What is a word for ‘not-fitting’?

Tags: single-word-requests

> I do not seem to fit within this social group. This ______ might be due to social anxiety.

For the blank above I want to use something that means ‘lack of fitting’, but cannot find a good word that conveys this idea. Is there one?

Comment: Something like [Word for "outcastness"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/380854/191178)?

Comment: Well, there's "ill-fit".

Comment: Just saying, an idiom would also fit, like : I feel like a fish out of the water. I am not fitting within this social group. Maybe it's because of social anxiety

Comment: The ***poor fit*** …

Comment: Probably "*awkwardness*" works best in this sentence.

Comment: to fit or fit in would not be used in the progressive tense here. I feel that I don't fit in to this social group. That said, if you don't fit in somewhere, most of the suggested answers do not work...

Answer (score 13):

Consider [**disconnect**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disconnect) as a somewhat more informal term. According to en.wiktionary.org:

> A lack of connection or accord; a mismatch.
> *There's a **disconnect** between what they think is happening and what is really going on.*

From the book [*College Hookup Culture and Christian Ethics: The Lives and Longings of Emerging Adults*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=1Xo7DwAAQBAJ&dq=the%20%22disconnect%22%20between%20the%20partygoers), page 63, we have this:

> Peer reactions ranged from puzzlement to outright hostility: I felt a
> **disconnect** between the more inebriated partygoers and myself. It is
> easy to see the role that group pressure plays in influencing people
> to drink.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest and most obvious noun is:

**misfit**

after the first and original definition, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misfit):

> 1 : something that fits badly

Example of usage:

> “If the wind is from the north-east , if a dress is a **misfit** , if people say…”

[An Autralian Girl, Catherine Martin, 2002]

Of course, *a misfit* has another, more common, meaning, but this describes the lack of fit, whereas words such as *alienation* describe the putative psychological feelings of the individual.

Another, less ambiguous, possibility, describing the actual state is:

[**discord**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discord)

but this tends to imply disagreement, which may not necessarily be present.

[**disharmony**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disharmony)

has less of an implication of disagreement, but perhaps too much of a musical tone.

[**incompatibility**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incompatibility)

is another possibility, although its contemporary use to describe personal relationships makes it less than perfect.

---

That’s my answer. However, in the absence of a perfect fit I personally would not go for a single word, but use a phrase like “lack of fit”, or simply use “This” as a back reference, to replace “The [...]” in the example. (But forget about social anxiety. They may just not be your type of people.)

Comment: The simplest might be with no noun:  “This might be due to social anxiety.”

Comment: *Misfit* works just fine; as you said, it's: *simplest and most obvious*.

Comment: @Jim I mentioned this in my footnote. The question was a one-word request, implicitly for a noun.

Comment: Most dictionaries see the abstract 'non-fittting' sense as so rare that they don't list it. A 'misfit' is almost always a person.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Context makes it clear, and the sentence has **The** not “A”.

Comment: This makes me think of a person first and foremost: "The misfit of the group". I think two word phrases do better than this single word that comes across a little awkward since isn't usually used like this ("poor fit", "bad fit").

Comment: Even in the archaic sense of the word that you are relying on to answer the question, this word still means "the single object that is a misfit", it is not the state of being or feeling like a misfit, so I think it's not a perfect solution for the OP.

Comment: @theonlygusti — Nice try, but I won't let you get away with that as neither Merriam-Webster nor Collins qualify this sense of "misfit" as archaic. And a Google ngram book search for "misfit shoe" brings up a number of recent examples, including one for 2019. And there is no reason to get into perception. If you are a tennis player and join a football club you won't fit in.

Comment: The thought that added context will clarify which sense is intended will not make an unidiomatic usage sound natural.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — "Unidiomatic"? It's a legitimate use of the word that educated people will understand. As far as context goes, the example consists of a sentence in which the poster states that he doesn't fit in — this is not **added** context, it is  **integral** context. As you will be aware, my natural response to questions that seek a single-word answer when a phrase would be better is to tell them. Generally someone down-votes my answer as not addressing the question. This time I have addressed the question and relegated my reservations to a footnote, only to open up the Eastern Front.

Comment: One data point: "This misfit might be due to social anxiety." would make me hesitate, re-read to ensure that I hadn't missed a word, force me to think about it, render me confused as to whether it was referring to a person or a situation, and probably end up with me irritated as to why the author hadn't written "lack of fit" (or maybe "failure to fit (in)") if they intended to refer to the situation.

Comment: Please ignore my edit summary.. I meant to replace "------" with "[...]", not underscores.

Answer (score 7):

**Alienation:**

OED

> **1.a. Estrangement; the state of being estranged or alienated.**
>
> 1966   J. Cheever Jrnls. (1991) 216   *He explained that I had developed a social veneer—an illusion of friendship—that was meant to conceal my basic hostility and alienation.*

And from [Study.com](https://study.com/academy/lesson/marx-on-alienation-definition-lesson-quiz.html):

> Generally speaking, the term alienation is used to describe a person who feels isolated from others or is prohibited from taking part in aspects of society in which he or she should otherwise be allowed to participate. For example, people who often perceive themselves or are perceived by others to be 'outsiders' or a 'social misfits' might find that they are unwelcome in certain areas of society and will therefore feel alienated from others because they don't fit in.

Also see the definition:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alienation)
> *alienation*
> the feeling that you have no connection with the people around you or that you are not part of a group:
> *Depressed people frequently feel a sense of alienation from those around them.*

Comment: A clear answer to which I took the liberty of adding a dictionary definition.

Comment: While absolutely fitting the requested definition, it’s probably worth noting that *alienation* has a much stronger tone than the example sentence suggests is warranted. (+1 either way, mind you, I just think that this should be mentioned prominently in the answer to make it the best it can be.)

Comment: To me, the word "alienation" makes it sound like the other people are excluding this person or being unwelcoming on purpose.

Comment: @TannerSwett It works both ways: 1966   J. Cheever 'Journals'. (1991) 216   *He explained that I had developed a social veneer—an illusion of friendship—that was meant to conceal my basic hostility and alienation.* -- 1971   B. Sidran 'Black Talk' v. 152   *This alienation from mainstream culture, then, remains basically a circular and unresolvable problem peculiar to the Negro.*

Answer (score 5):

I suggest "[incompatibility](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incompatibility)."

> I feel that I am not fitting within this social group. The *incompatibility* might be due to social anxiety.

An example sentence from the definition page at the online Merriam-Webster dictionary (merriam-webster.com), linked above:

> The pair’s incompatibility became immediately obvious once the expedition left Zanzibar. — Gary Krist, Washington Post, 27 May 2022

The definition of incompatibility links to [incompatible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incompatible) at Merriam-Webster: "incapable of association or harmonious coexistence."

Comment: This is another suggestion with the right connotations. Several of the others sound too formal or too slangy in this context, for me, but would work in a different sentence.

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you. I have made edits, adding plain text showing that the definitions come from Merriam-Webster. I hope this is satisfactory.

Answer (score 4):

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/inadequacy?q=inadequacy)) **inadequacy** [uncountable] a state of not being able or confident to deal with a situation
>
> - a feeling/sense of inadequacy

It is a word, which when given the meaning of "social unfitness" is mostly used in one of the two combinations shown in the dictionary defintion. ([sense of inadequacy](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sense%20of%20inadequacy%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [feeling of inadequacy](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22feeling%20of%20inadequacy%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

- I feel that I am not fitting within this social group. The sense/feeling of inadequacy might be due to social anxiety.

Comment: How can you equate "lack of fitting" as "inadequacy"? I may not fit into a social group because I feel that the ideas and interests of the members are trivial and stupid. This is certainly not a feeling of inadequacy.

Comment: @David If one reads carefully the words in the OP's explanation, one  sees that the person does not recognize themselves as not  fitting: they _seem_ not to fit in the group— maybe they are subject to a misapprehension of the situation—. finally, one reads that this problem might be due to _social anxiety_, which everyone knows, is a mere passing and subjective state of mind more or less easy to overcome; here is again the notion that the person does not consider themselves to be a misfit and that they merely have a feeling of not fitting in, not belonging; is that not a feeling of inadequacy?

Answer (score 4):

Probably "*awkwardness*" works best in your sentence.  As in:

> I feel that I am not fitting within this social group. The *awkwardness* might be due to social anxiety.

Comment: This is the most natural sounding answer for the example sentence.

Answer (score 3):

**mismatch**

> a failure to correspond or match; a discrepancy

Oxford English Dictionary

This word might have the disadvantage of focussing more on the reasons to not fit in, "not-like-the-others" because of fashion, ideology, or some other superficial reason. The result and the mental state, the "I feel alienated" feelings, are better captured by other words (like "incongruence").

Comment: This is the word I would use. Several of the others technically work, but are either too formal or too informal.

Answer (score 2):

While — somewhat paradoxically, isn't it? ;-) — *misfit* is the best fit, we should mention **awkward** which describes exactly the discomfort and *alienation* one feels when one is a bad fit, *inadequate,* an *outcast.* If you indeed must use a noun, it would be the less elegant *awkwardness.*

Answer (score 2):

**incongruence**

> the state of not being suitable or not fitting well with something else

Cambridge Dictionary

This word strongly suggests feeling out of place. You are a puzzle piece that doesn't fit in the jigsaw that is this social group. Something's not quite right, and it's a mental dissonance.

Comment: perhaps Incongruity in the context of the sentence. But I agree with this one.

Answer (score 1):

One idiom is, according to [Wikipedia - "fish out of water"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_out_of_water):

> "Fish out of water" is an idiom used to refer to a person who is in unfamiliar, and often uncomfortable, surroundings.

Another idiomatic expression,  according to [Wikipedia - "square peg in a round hole"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole):

> "Square peg in a round hole" is an idiomatic expression which describes the unusual individualist who could not fit into a niche of their society.

Answer (score 1):

**disharmony**

> lack of harmony or agreement: *we will become evermore a nation of social disharmony.*

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/disharmony)

This word makes the reader think about the group as a whole more so than some other words. It's less about the individual's lack of fitting in, and more about the whole group's state when the individual is hanging around it.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised not to see ***unfit***.

As in: "this is plain *unfit* for service." Or often used in farm grade products, but could be used in a social situation.

*unfit for human consumption*

Answer (score -1):

Something that fits well in your sentence because of the context, and suggests a negative mood and sadness, would be simply:

### failure

> 1. lack of success
> 3. the action or state of not functioning

Oxford English Dictionary

The narrator feels that their inability to fit in with the group is some dysfunction or shortcoming. Using this word gives the phrase some emotional leaning, unlike other words which may be purely analytical. It fits very well in your sentence though.

Answer (score -1):

How about ***dis-ease*** - absence of ease; uneasiness, discomfort; inconvenience, annoyance; disquiet, disturbance; trouble.

This usage, which predates the common current meaning ('illness'), was for long obsolete but has revived in modern use with the hyphenated spelling (OED) -

[image]

([Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dis-ease%2Cdis+-+ease&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3))

Comment: You can't really rely on Ngrams processing of hyphenation to be reliable. Dis-ease appears frequently in medical books referring to medical disease.

Comment: @barbecue - no doubt, the medical sense (without hyphen) is the dominant sense.  I sometimes use the other sense I suggest here and the ngram supports this.  The hyphen serves to distinguish the two meanings.

Comment: There are no links on the Google Ngram for examples which appear in print, which suggest that the instances are extremely rare. Compare those results with "unease", [beneath the Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dis-ease%2Cdis+-+ease%2C+unease&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdis%20-%20ease%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdis%20--%20ease%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunease%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdis%20-%20ease%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdis%20--%20ease%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunease%3B%2Cc0) you find a link showing the instances of usage.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thanks for that - hoist by my own petard!  I can only say that I, and others I know, *do* use dis-ease in the sense I offer here.  Both the OED and Merriam concur that it is a contemporary usage, whatever Ngrams may (be able to) measure - https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/word-history-of-disease

Comment: @Dan what I meant was that Ngrams will encounter the word disease hyphenated in medical texts simply due to the normal hyphenation of words which occurs in published texts. The word will be hyphenated because it's at the end of a line, and Ngrams doesn't know the difference.

Comment: @barbecue - yes, I understand.  Ngram - in my hands at least - is clearly not the tool to establish the difference between dis-ease (illness) when it's hyphenated due to (eg) a line break and dis-ease when it's hyphenated (as described by OED and Merriam) to make clear the meaning I put in my answer.